# How to retrieve all Test Cases in a Test Plan via TFS API?

Tags: c#, tfs

Using the TFS 2015 API, I am attempting to get all test cases under a test plan. I am currently running into the issue where I am retrieving all the test cases in a test plan, but the way I am pulling in the test cases is giving me collection of *distinct* test cases in a test plan. I would like all test case IDs, including duplicate test case IDs in the event we are testing various configurations of a particular test in that test plan.

I ultimately want to be able to access the result of all configurations of a test case via the API.

Below is the method I am using to pull in test cases for a specified test plan ID:

```
public ITestCaseCollection
TestPlan_GetAllTestCasesByPlanId(ITestManagementTeamProject testproject, int id)
{
    var plans = testproject.TestPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan");
    var planById = plans.First(x => x.Id == id);
    return planById.RootSuite.AllTestCases;
}
```

Say I have a test plan with 10 distinct test cases with two different configurations for each case. Therefore there will ultimately be 20 test case scenarios in that plan now with 20 possible outcomes during the test run. Using the above method, it is only pulling in the 10 distinct test cases.

I have tried drilling down into each `ITestSuiteEntry` in the plan, using the below method, but it only hits the suites directly under the plan. It doesn't account for nested suites.

```
public ITestCaseResultCollection GetTestCaseResults(ITestManagementTeamProject testproject, int id)
{
    var plans = testproject.TestPlans.Query("Select * from TestPlan");
    var planById = plans.First(x => x.Id == id);

    foreach(ITestSuiteEntry suiteEntry in planById.RootSuite.Entries)
    {
        var testSuite = suiteEntry.TestSuite;
        foreach(ITestSuiteEntry subSuiteEntry in testSuite.TestCases)
        {    
            var testCaseResults = testproject.TestResults.ByTestId(subSuiteEntry.TestCase.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access every configuration of every test case in a plan so I can collect their test outcomes? Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with below powershell script:

```
$ProjectName = "foo"
$TfsServerUrl = "http://tfsserverurl:8080/tfs/bar"
$testPlanName = "testplanname"

#===================================================
#     Settings
#===================================================

Write-Host "Input parameters: "
$ParamObject = @{
 'ProjectName' = $ProjectName;
 'TfsServerUrl' = $TfsServerUrl;
 'testPlanName' = $testPlanName;
}
$ParamObject | Format-Table

#===================================================
#    Main Script Body
#===================================================

  #load assemblies
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client")
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common")
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client")
    #get TFS structure, project
 $tfs = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection]::GetFullyQualifiedUriForName($tfsServerUrl));
 $tms = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementService]);
 $project = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementTeamProject]$tms.GetTeamProject($ProjectName);
 #powershell bug workaround, $project.TestPlans property is not available
 $testPlansProperty = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementTeamProject].GetProperty("TestPlans").GetGetMethod();
 $testPlans = $testPlansProperty.Invoke($project, "instance,public", $null, $null, $null);
#   List all Test Plans
 foreach($p in $testPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan"))
 {
  "Plan - {0} : {1}" -f $p.Id, $p.Name
 }
 $currentPlan = $testPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan Where planName = '{0}'" -f $testPlanName)
 $plan = $currentPlan | where {$_.Name -eq $testPlanName}

 $testCases = $plan.RootSuite.AllTestCases


 foreach($testCase in $testCases)
 {
  write-host ""
  write-host "-----------"
  write-host "START - Test Case"  $testCase.Id
   write-host "Parameters:"

$testCase.TestSuiteEntry.TestCase.DefaultTable  
  write-host "-----------"
}
```

Reference:

- [Get all Test Cases from Test Plan](http://mypowershell.webnode.sk/news/get-all-test-cases-from-test-plan/)
- [TFS API Part 27 – Test Plans, Test Suites, Test Cases Mapping](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/07/06/tfs-api-part-27-test-plans-test-suites-test-cases-mapping/)
- [Code snippets on Test Management APIs?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2012/08/06/code-snippets-on-test-management-apis/)